# What column(s) should be handled when clone a new file to SharePoint library in C#?

Tags: sharepoint-server

In my project, I have to upload a new file to SharePoint library which base on specific existing item.

For example:

```
The original library have 2 items which has 10 custom columns:
itemA: c1 c2 c3 c4 c5 c6 c7 c8 c9 c10
itemB: v1 v2 v3 v4 v5 v6 v7 v8 v9 v10
```

But now, I have to upload a new item (itemC) which its **all**  columns value are clone from itemA (include build-in columns, Author,Editor, etc.).

```
Now:
itemA: c1 c2 c3 c4 c5 c6 c7 c8 c9 c10
itemB: v1 v2 v3 v4 v5 v6 v7 v8 v9 v10
itemC: c1 c2 c3 c4 c5 c6 c7 c8 c9 c10
```

I have tried to get all columns and its value, dataType via SPFieldCollection. However, there are too many columns (75) which I don't know which one should be kept.

```
var interalName = field.InternalName;
var TypeDisplayName  = field.TypeDisplayName;
var dataType:  field.Type;
var value = item[interalName];
```

Result:
too many, I list 3 of those build-in column:

```
--------------------------------------
field name: MetaInfo
field TypeDisplayName : Lookup
field dataType: Lookup
field value: vti_thumbnailexists:BW|false
------------------------------------------
field name: DocIcon
field TypeDisplayName : Computed
field dataType: Computed
field value: png
-----------------------------------------
field name: _EditMenuTableStart2
field TypeDisplayName : Computed
field dataType: Computed
field value: 146
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to copy only c1 c2 c3 c4 c5 c6 c7 c8 c9 c10 columns. Other columns are internal columns to maintain some other metadata. Also Created By/ modified by cannot be copied from itemA, it will be updated based on the user uploading / updating the metadata.

Comment: Thank you for your answer,  but i do need to keep the Created By/ modified .. value of the newest item as same as the specific item (itemA). I find that there are a System.Update(). Do you have any idea to do this?

Comment: If you are using server side code then you can keep the created by / modified by same as itemA but in case you are using CSOM code (jQuery/ javascript) to update the values then you cannot update Created by / modified by.

Comment: Sorry, two more questions,  1) how can i identify which column is custom column or build-in column? 2) how to handle some column which of type Look up?

Comment: Are you using server side code or client side scripting ?

Comment: I am using server side code

Comment: You have two options:

1. Check if the field is a built-in field:   SPBuiltInFieldId.Contains(field.Id)    2. Check on the SPField.SourceId (from MSDN):

Gets either the namespace that defines a built-in field or, if it a custom field, the GUID that identifies the list or Web site where it was created.

Reference from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5340746/custom-fields-only-from-sharepoint-list

Comment: THX XD !!! It works prefect to identify  build-in columns and custom column.